# Obj-c/Cocoa touch: Have UITableViewCell - CellTextField only accept Numeric chars?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to have a CellTextField within a UITableViewCell only accept numeric chars.
I programmatically create UITableViewCells like this:

```
    -(UITableViewCell*) getCellContentView: (NSString*) cellIdentifier {

        ...

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        ... 

        CellTextField *txt;  
        txt = [[CellTextField alloc] initWithFrame:amountFrame];

        ... //here we should setup a delegate or similar to handle char validation for txt

        [cell.contentView addSubview:txt];
        return cell;
    }
```

For the UITextField component we have a Delegate 'shouldChangeCharactersInRange' but I can't find the equivalent for CellTextFields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

.h

```
  @interface YourClass : ParentClass <UITextFieldDelegate>{
  NSNumberFormatter *integerNumberFormatter;
  }
  @end
```

.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
      [integerNumberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
       yourTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString* proposedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSNumber *proposedNumber = [integerNumberFormatter numberFromString:proposedString];
    if (proposedNumber) {
        NSString *integerString = [integerNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:proposedNumber];
        if ([integerString isEqualToString:proposedString]) {
            // proposed string is an integer
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: How would I proceed to actually connect this with a specific  (programmatically created) CellTextField?

Comment: I assume CellTextField is a type of UITextField , isnt it?

Comment: CellTextField must be a subclass of UITextField. In this case you can register your class as a delegate to the CellTextField instance.

Comment: Can you show me where shouldChangeCharactersInRange is referenced elsewhere? I can't quite get my head around that. I have many various textfields in the view but I only want this check for a specific few.

Comment: are you using this class? http://apiexplorer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/UICatalog/TableCells/CellTextField.h   if so , notice that it implements UITextFieldDelegate. you can just add the code above in its .m and .h respectively if you want

Comment: Nah. It inherits UITextField and adds one extra member is all. Seems like I have to check some more Objective-C delegate examples.

Comment: One problem I had was that I was already using shouldChangeCharactersInRange for a UITextField with a different purpose within 'YourClass'. Since there is only one other textField in the view though I just do a simple check now if it's this instance or not (if not I use the numberFormatter logic you have detailed above). Thanks.